# SSH key creation in stand alone machine

Tags: key-authentication, ssh-keygen

is it possible to create ssh keys (ssh-keygen) in stand alone machine. and then copy private ssh and public ssh key to client ssh directory and server ssh directory to perform password less authentication between client to server ?

Comment: Yes, this is not different from how it's usually done. The server does not need the private key though.

Comment: Are you asking about generating SSH key on one machine (stand alone) and then using it on another machine? Yes that is possible by simply copying and pasting the private key and public key in SSH directory. Take care to not copy private key to server.

Comment: @udiboy1209, Thanks ! your answer matches exactly what i was looking for. I already did the same and it worked before i checked this answer. the reason i have asked this question because i had a thought that Private key are specific to machines (where we create keys) and not transferable. but that proved wrong now.

Comment: i was expecting private key to be copied to another host (which is not going to be ssh server, instead ssh client) to perform password less authentication from that host

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, you don't want to put the private key on the server, you are doing public key authentication for passwordless ssh. You can ignore the private key.

Run   `ssh-keygen`

This will create a public key something like:

```
/home/myhome/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Put this public key into the authorized keys file on the server.

You do need need to use the `ssh-copy-id` to copy it to the remote host, you can just add it yourself.

Comment: i did exactly the same, but also copied private key to another host from where i would try execute ssh session with password less. it worked. i just wanted to confirm whether the private keys are Host Specific (where we created). result from my testing proved to be its not.

Comment: i completely agree private key is not supposed to be moved. but my requirement is different

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This is how to do it.

1) On your machine, generate a 2048-bit RSA keypair:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048 -N ''
```

2) On remote SSH server, allow public key authentication by setting `PubkeyAuthentication yes` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

3) On your machine, copy your public key to the SSH server:

```
ssh-copy-id yourlogin@sshserver
```

Note that you must **not** copy your private key to the SSH server, just your public key.

Comment: my requirement itself is whether moving private key to another machine and achieve password less authentication between client and this machine i copied the key to. I completely agree private keys are not supposed to be moved.